# Is this view hierarchy(two surfaceviews and two custom views) possible?

Tags: android, view, surfaceview

Assume there are 4 views named A, B, C, D. A and C are SurfaceViews, B and D are custom Views. Is it possible A is behind B which is behind C which is behind D?

From this link(http://pierrchen.blogspot.com/2014/03/anroid-graphics-surfaceview-all-you.html), "By default, the Window for SurfaceView has lower z-order than the Application Window."

Comment: does it have be `SurfaceView`? what about `TextureView`?

Comment: @pskink, If the answer is impossible, I have to use TextureView. Since SurfaceView is rendered in a secondary thread, I prefer SurfaceView.

Comment: you can render `TextureView` in a secondary thread too

Comment: @pskink, how? Could you plz give some related material? Thanks.

Comment: see setSurfaceTextureListener and onSurfaceTextureAvailable